# sending email with Indy to a gmail address message goes to spam

Tags: delphi, email, gmail, send, indy

Hello I'm trying to send a message from delphi (indy) to a gmail address. When I go to Gmail I found my message in spam folder. If I try to send the same message with PHPMailer from web it works correctly. This is the code.

Thanks

```
//setup SMTP
SMTP.Port := 25;
SMTP.ConnectTimeout := 1000;
SMTP.Host := 'smtp.xxxxxx.it';
SMTP.Username := 'info@xxxxxx.it';
SMTP.Password := 'xxxxxx';
SMTP.Connect();

if SMTP.Authenticate then
begin
    //setup mail message
    MailMessage.From.Name := 'xxxxxx';
    MailMessage.From.Address := 'info@xxxxxx.it';
    MailMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := 'xxxxxx@gmail.com';

    MailMessage.Subject := ledSubject.Text;
    MailMessage.ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
    htmpart := TIdText.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, nil);
    htmpart.Body := Body.Lines;
    htmpart.ContentType := 'text/html';

    //send mail
    try
        try
            SMTP.Send(MailMessage);
        except on E:Exception do
            StatusMemo.Lines.Insert(0, 'ERROR: ' + E.Message);
        end;
    finally
        if SMTP.Connected then SMTP.Disconnect;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Then the Gmail spam filter doesn't like your `info@xxxxxx.it` address.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emails send from my domain are going into spam](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14018540/emails-send-from-my-domain-are-going-into-spam).

Comment: @TLama Perhaps GMail is also skeptic towards email agent? The question says mails sent from PHPMailer are not considered spam.

Comment: @iManBiglari, I missed that. Yeah, that might be the way to workaround. [+1]

Answer (score 4):

Probably I've found the problem. I look the message in 'original mode' I found in the header that google says 'MISSING ID' and I try to add this code:

```
    MailMessage.MsgId := '1234567890@drinkmessage.it';
    MailMessage.ExtraHeaders.Values['Message-Id'] := MailMessage.MsgId;
```

Now it seems to work fine.

thanks

Comment: You don't need to use the `ExtraHeaders` property, just use the `MsgId` property by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing `HeloName` and `MailAgent` of `IdSMTP`? If you use the same domain with PHPMailer, my guess is GMail considers emails coming from your application as spam because it doesn't detect/like the application which is sending them.